# Background Image Mobile Responsive with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, background-image

I've tried Bootstrap's .img-responsive and other options but the background image on my mobile device is still blown up and pixelated. Mobile view on desktop browser is fine, but on actual mobile device, the image is skewed. Any help is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="hero">
    <div class="landing">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <img src="/website_v2/img/headline-work-play-contactics.png" class="shadow-offset img-responsive">                
            </div> <!-- /.col -->
          </div> <!-- /.row -->
        </div> <!-- /.wrapper -->
      </div> <!-- /.container -->
    </div> <!-- /.landing -->
</div> <!-- /.hero -->
```

CSS:

```
.hero .landing {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: url(../img/hero-index.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #d3d3d3;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox */
    -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
    -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera */
    animation: fadein 1s;
}

.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.hero .container {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.hero .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-animation: aniload .5s;
    -moz-animation: aniload .5s;
    -ms-animation: aniload .5s;
    -o-animation: aniload .5s;
    animation: aniload .5s;
}

.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: what are the dimensions of the image?

Comment: @RyanHollingsworth - background image is 1620 × 1080.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in your grid system
Here `col-md-8` for medium device like as Tablet.For mobile device you should use  `col-sm-12`.I think that will be work fine now.For details please see bootstrap grid system http://getbootstrap.com/css/

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">

</div>
```

In css there

```
img {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is the image tag in the HTML, but the background-image in the CSS. Although, I did set a class of "col-sm-12" to ".landing" div in HTML because I thought that would fix it. But it didn't. So, I think I need a solution to the CSS ".hero .landing".

Answer (score 0):

```
.img-responsive{
 height:auto; 
 width:100%
}
```

apply this code in mobile media queries section